# Can you construct "one-off" factories in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I would like to use FactoryGirl to create one-off factories. That is, the Factory doesn't exist anymore as soon as it's out of scope.

Most factories are defined with something like:

```
Factory.define(:user) do
  first_name "James"
  last_name  "Smith"
end

u = Factory.build(:user)
```

But doing it this way means that FactoryGirl holds a reference to the `:user` factory forever. No matter where you are, `Factory.build(:user)` means the one you defined earlier. What I want is something like this:

```
f = Factory.temporary(:user) do
  first_name "David"
  last_name  "Jones"
end

u = f.build
```

As soon as `f` goes out of scope, you can't refer to it anymore, so there will be no danger of polluting your object space with factories that aren't used. (If I want a one-off factory that is only used in a particular test, I don't want it exposed to the rest of my tests. That's sloppy.)

Is that possible? If not, is there a gem that will let me do something equivalent?

Comment: Why not just override the user factory with the attributes that you want? `Factory.build :user, :first_name => 'David', :last_name => 'Jones'`

Comment: @James Because that requires loading all of my factories before I can do anything, and almost all of those factories are useless for a given test. That's bad isolation and it's sloppy testing. "If you want to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first create the universe" is a nice Carl Sagan quote, but it shouldn't apply to writing unit tests.

Comment: If you want a one-off factory for specific tests, my guess is that factories aren't the right pattern, and you'd be better served with something like `let(:user) { User.new(:first_name => 'David', :last_name => 'TooSoon') }` or just mocks+stubs.

Comment: @BenTaitelbaum That would work, but then I don't get to leverage useful behavior that FactoryGirl provides (`after_build`, etc.) and I'd have to write that myself. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky, but:

```
module FactoryGirl
  class Registry
    def remove(name)
      @items[name.to_sym] = nil
    end
  end
end

before do
  Factory(:my_user, :parent => :user) do |f|
    f.first_name "David"
  end
end

after do
  FactoryGirl.factories.remove(:my_user)
end
```